# Oracle Internet Directory 12.2.1.3.0 Error occurred while performing invoke : Creation of wallets failed for domain

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, wlst, oid

After successfully installing Oracle Internet Directory 12.2.1.3.0, I am able to connect with this command

```
connect('weblogic','Oracle20_1','t3://MYPC:7001')
```

but when I issue this command

```
oid_setup(orcladminPassword='Oracle20_1',odsPassword='Oracle20_1',realmDN='dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com')
```

I get the error below.

```
Starting an edit session ...
Started edit session, be sure to save and activate your changes once you are done.
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
  File "/D:/Installations/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oid/plugins/wlst/oid-wlst-dependencies.jar!/wlstScriptDir/OidCustomCommands.py", line 14, in oid_setup
  File "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oid\plugins\wlst\oid-wlst-dependencies.jar\wlstScriptDir/oid_handler.py", line 274, in oid_doSetup
  File "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\modules\com.oracle.weblogic.management.scripting.jar\weblogic/management/scripting/utils/modules/wlstModule.py", line 38, in invoke
  File "C:\Users\MYPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wlst_module17230875974479771820.py", line 753, in wlstInvoke
  File "C:\Users\MYPC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wlst_module33031062050886075784.py", line 240, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing invoke : Creation of wallets failed for domain "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain15"
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
wls:/mydomain15/editCustom/oracle.oid.mbeans/oracle.oid.mbeans:type=OIDSystemComponent,name=OIDComponentManager>
```

Comment: was the process stopped with "CTRL+z" and moved to the background ?

Comment: James Z, thank you very much for your response. I did not stop the process with "CTRL + z". I have used several means, including restarting the server to resolve the issue but I am still getting this error

Comment: Please execute dumpStack() after getting the error and attach the full stacktrace

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.3/inoim/configuring-product-domain.html#GUID-982B779F-C17B-49D4-B4A5-08D25916DA4C)? I've seen there are two ways to configure OID, standalone and collocated, which one are you using?

Comment: I followed all the steps. I am using collected. I will execute the dumpStock() and attach briefly

Comment: This Exception occurred at Sun Aug 23 12:58:19 GMT 2020.
javax.management.MBeanException: Creation of wallets failed for domain "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain15"
        at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Creation of wallets failed for domain "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain15"
        ... 1 more

javax.management.MBeanException: Creation of wallets failed for domain "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain15"

Comment: Above is the result after executing dumpStack()